# cloud firestore rules timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this structure in firestore[image]

I need to limit access to data where expirationTimestamp > now
I have found this example

```
match /collection/{document} {
  allow read: if request.time < resource.data.expirationTimestamp;
}
```

but I always get "Simulated data access denied"

[image]

anyone know why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`request.time` is known not to work in the Firestore console simulator. Any reference to `request.time` immediately (and incorrectly) rejects access in the simulator.  It should work fine for fully published rules.

Comment: I have tried to publish this rules but my app says "Error: Missing or insufficient permissions."

Comment: Are you sure you want to use [date()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp#date)?  Maybe a different method on a Timestamp is more appropriate?

Comment: I have tried with only "request.time" but it still not works

Comment: Perhaps you should read through the api docs for Timestamp in security rules to learn how they work.  If you're still stuck, consider asking a new question that doesn't involve the simulator, since it currently doesn't work with `request.time`.